# Goreplay: Request Rewriting not working as expected when using dynamic variables

Tags: traffic-simulation

I am using following tar: gor_1.3.3_x64.tar.gz

Gor command used:
./gor --input-raw :3000 --output-http="http://athena-service.uranus.svc.cluster.local" 
--http-rewrite-url "/**onemg-internal**/end_user/v1/drug_skus/(\d+)/dynamic:/pharma-pdp/v1/drug/dynamic/$1" 
--http-allow-url "/**onemg-internal**/end_user/v1/drug_skus/(\d+)/dynamic"

Request is being received at the output server, but the regex group is not captured inside $1.
[Request received at the output server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feJHF.png)

As you can see in the above SS, the uri is /pharma-pdp/v1/drug/dynamic/ while it should have been /pharma-pdp/v1/drug/dynamic/1234.

Can somebody help with this?

I tried using different regex, but nothing worked.
Expecting a resolution or atleast the problem if somebody have encountered this issues before.

Answer (score 0):

Using single qoute instead of double qoute should work

```
--http-rewrite-url '/onemg-internal/end_user/v1/drug_skus/(\d+)/dynamic:/pharma-pdp/v1/drug/dynamic/$1'
```